# detect object in image,how they did it. I think it is unbelieveable

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, computer-vision

[alt text http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/examples/person_06.jpg](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/examples/person_06.jpg)
[alt text http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/examples/dog_08.jpg](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/examples/dog_08.jpg)
[alt text http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/examples/sheep_07.jpg](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/examples/sheep_07.jpg)

this picture is download from a website,the team show their research result like this.
I want to know how they did it, some body know tell me I will be appreciate.  thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we have websites url? If it's public?

As for your question, it's most likely neural networks. I doubt anyone could tell you the exact way they did it. There can be many ways after all. But I'm no expert in this area.

Comment: I will tell you the website. http://lear.inrialpes.fr/
see it by yourself

Comment: Well, English is not my mother tongue, but I'm still pretty sure I didn't say anything remotely bad. Thanks for url.

Comment: They hardly ever use neural networks. Look through the papers: it is SVM.

Comment: By the way, pattern-matching tag is misleading, please remove it. Real computer vision systems don't perform any image matching (maybe feature matching, but it's different). Also, pattern matching is usually about text matching, i.e. regexps, not about images.

Comment: "Object detection in images and videos has received a lot of attention in the computer vision and
pattern recognition communities in recent years." this is dalal's phD thesis's text .So I want to say pattern-matching tag is not misleading

Comment: perhaps `pattern-recognition` is more fitting

Comment: Sure, pattern recognition and pattern matching are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on their [publications](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/), one can conclude they use SVM classifier and/or some sort of a graphical model (Markov Random Field / Conditional Random Field). Also, they (probably) use Histograms of Oriented Gradients as features. The approach implies really complicated math (machine learning, to be precise). If you are not familiar, you could try to use their [implementation](http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/soft/olt/).

Answer (score 8):

The [algorithm](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2008/KMS08/KlaserMarszalekSchmid-BMVC08-3DGradientDescriptor.pdf) was published.

And you can redo it yourself, if you do have your Math skills sharp enough.